# Getting the typing rate of a user

Tags: android

I am developing an app where I need to find the typing rate of a user, not from that particular app, from all the app he uses, like when he is texting in WhatsApp or Facebook. I dont need the words typed, just the average number of words typed in a minute ,I heard its stored in some metadata, Is it possible to achieve it?

Comment: `I heard its stored in some metadata` I don't think it is. You may want to develop your own keyboard app, and calculate this info in that app.